# How to create sliding drawer in both sides opposite to one another?

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer

I have added the code that working for right to left sliding perfectly but i want sliding from left to right also  so check the layout and help me out.Here i have mentioned the layout properly for right to left ,Is it possible to get the Slider window in both sides i mean left and right horizontally...

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
              <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@drawable/bg"
         android:orientation="vertical" >
       <Button
        android:id="@+id/ship"
        android:layout_width="186dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:background="@drawable/signup"
        android:text="Shipping Calculator"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
<SlidingDrawer
  android:id="@+id/drawer"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:handle="@+id/handle"
  android:content="@+id/content">
  <ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/handle"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
   android:src="@drawable/tag"/>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/slidimage"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:padding="10dp" >
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
            android:text="SIGN-UP"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

  </LinearLayout>
 </SlidingDrawer>
 <SlidingDrawer
  android:id="@+id/drawers"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:handle="@+id/handles"
  android:layout_gravity="left"
  android:scrollX="100dp"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:content="@+id/contents">
  <ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/handles"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_gravity="left"
   android:src="@drawable/tag"/>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/contents"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="left"
      android:background="@drawable/slidimage"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:padding="10dp" >
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
            android:text="SIGN-UP"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>
 </SlidingDrawer> 

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer here statically its not exactly possible to create sliding ,and we cant use android:rotation=180 ,as because it will display error as no resource found, We have to create it programatically.it needs to add view in layout.

In case of single side its  simple by using widget only no need any views..But the views are needed when you want to slide in multiple direction.

```
<SlidingDrawer
  android:id="@+id/drawer"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:handle="@+id/handle"
  android:content="@+id/content">
  <ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/handle"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
   android:src="@drawable/tag"/>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/slidimage"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:padding="10dp" >
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
            android:text="SIGN-UP"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

  </LinearLayout>
 </SlidingDrawer>
```

activity.java:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.slider);

}
```

Comment: Thank you , this solution is working fine for me but i need the direction from left to right , the solution makes the sliding come from right to left , any solution?

Comment: @Muhannad yes..for that reason check the below link http://seasonofrejoice.blogspot.in/2013/01/sliding-drawer-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

I've created a replacement widget for SlidingDrawer, it works in all directions.  See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17605645/1516170)